# Convergence of a sequence of densities

Tags: real-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence

Consider a sequence of functions $f_n:[0,1] \rightarrow (0,1)$ and a function $g:[0,1] \rightarrow (0,1) $ such that

\begin{equation}
\forall x,y, \lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty}{\frac{f_n(x)}{f_n(y)}}=\frac{g (x)}{g(y)}
\end{equation}

and
\begin{equation}
\forall n \in \mathbb {N}, \int{f_n(x)dx=1}
\end{equation}

I am trying to show that these conditions imply
\begin{equation}
\forall x \in [0,1], f_n (x) \rightarrow \frac{g(x)}{\int{g(y)dy}}
\end{equation}

Any help would be much appreciated. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If we also have that for a particular $x \in [0,1],\inf_n(x)f_n(x) = k_x>0,$ then we have that $$\left|\frac{f_n(y)}{f_n(x)}\right| \leq h(y) := \frac{1}{k_x} <\infty .$$ Now, since $h(y)$ is integrable over $[0,1]$, by dominated convergence we have that $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\int \frac{f_n(y)}{f_n(x)}dy = \int \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{f_n(y)}{f_n(x)}dy.$$

Now, we have that $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{f_n(x)} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\frac{\int f_n(y)dy}{f_n(x)}\right) = \lim_{n \to \infty}\left( \int \frac{f_n(y)}{f_n(x)}dy \right) = \int \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{f_n(y)}{f_n(x)}dy = \int \frac{g(y)}{g(x)}dy = \frac{\int g(y)dy}{g(x)}.$$

Comment: Thanks! One question: I don't understand how you define $h$. Shouldn't $h$ be independent of $n$ to apply the dominated convergence theorem?

Comment: @Oliv ... yes, i left out an important detail. Define it as the supremum  over $n$....by your second condition in the question it is integrable for all $n$ so it is still integrable.

Comment: @oliv actually I'm not sure if that's true...let me think about it.

Comment: Actually we don't even know that $h$ is well defined, do we? I am wondering if we need extra conditions, for instance that the sequence $f_n(x)$ has a positive lower bound for all $x$, for the result to be true. Or is that implied by the assumptions?

Comment: I had originally thought it was implied by the assumptions, but that seems unfounded. Are you integrating over a finite set, or are you integrating over a subset of the reals with infinite (lebesque) measure? If finite, then the condition $\inf_n f_n(x)=m>0$ is sufficient.

Comment: It is over $[0,1]$. I have the intuition (but no proof) that this condition is implied by the assumptions: since $f_n(y)$ is asymptotically proportional to $f_n (x)$, if $f_n(x)$ is unbounded below I guess the integral cannot equal 1 forever.

Comment: @Oliv I believe you may be right, but I'll have to take a better look at it later today.

Comment: @Oliv I believe I have a proof that no additional assumptions are required...though it is somewhat lengthy. I will edit my answer with a sketch of it today after I verify it. The idea is that if for any $x \in [0,1]$ that $\inf_n f_n(x) = 0$ then this must be true for all $x \in [0,1]$ (otherwise the ratio will not converge to a finite positive number for some monotone subsequence). This leads to a contradiction of the condition that the integral is $1$ for some $k$ large enough on that monotone subsequence where $f_{n_k}(x) \to 0$ for all $x$.